# Website isn't responsive in comparison to an almost identical one (links provided)

Tags: html, css, responsive

Update: I was missing the viewport  tag in head.

I have two websites, only one is responsive. The entire website seems to be lacking something that makes everything (not just elements I've applied columns or responsive elements to) appear larger on mobile devices. Given that this is a very broad question I could scope the problem to only the headers/navbars in both websites:

If you visit both in a mobile device you'll notice the difference immediately.

Both use SemanticUI library, the outer code for both headers is the same, the second header text doesn't scale on mobile. for some reason. **That's the case with almost every other part of the second website.**

First Site (responsive header):

```
<div class="ui fixed icon menu">
  <div class="header item">
    <%= image_tag "logo.png" %>
  </div>
  <%= header_link "Inicio", root_path %>
  <%= header_link "Quiénes Somos", about_path %>
  <%= header_link "Proyectos", project_path %>
  <%= header_link "Galería", gallery_path %>
  <div class="right menu">
    <a href="#" class="item contact-modal">
      <p id="contact">Contacto</p>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Second Site (non-responsive):

```
<div class="ui fixed icon menu">
  <div class="header item">
    <span>Em</span><span>erg</span><span>enc</span><span>y Ki</span><span>ts</span>
  </div>
  <%= link_to root_path, class: "item" do %>
    Inicio
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to distributors_path, class: "item" do %>
    Distribuidores
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to "#", class: "contact-modal item" do %>
    Contacto
  <% end %>
  <div class="right menu">
    .
    .
    .
    <div class="item">
      <i class="user icon"></i>
      <%= link_to "Iniciar Sesión", new_user_session_path, class: "logged-out" %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay. So what's your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly mistake, forgot the viewport  tag